# Javascript, retorno de requisição ajax, gerar arquivo

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
 newXHR.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
 newXHR.open('POST', 'http://nfse.vitoria.es.gov.br/aberto/op/imprimirNfe.cfm', false);
 var jsonData = { codNfe: vlNota };
 var formattedJsonData = "codNfe=" + vlNota;
 newXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8');
 newXHR.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
 newXHR.setRequestHeader('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', '1');
 newXHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 newXHR.responseType = "arraybuffer";
}catch(ex) {
 console.log('Erro ao abrir a URL');
 return false;
}
```

esse código me retorn um pdf, queria como faço para criar um arquivo com os dados que recebo dessa request

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer retornar o PDF ou um link onde o cara clica e ele realiza o download?

Comment: eu quero salvar um pdf no meu pc com essas informações